# Inverse crop in GIMP

Tags: gimp, selections, crop

I have an image that has blocks of useful content and blocks of useless content. I would like to remove the blocks of useless content without copy/pasting all of the useful content into another image.

Basically, is there a way to remove a stripe of an image?

Zealous crop does not want to remove transparent areas.

here's a sample image, with useless content deleted already: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use <kbd>R</kbd> (Rectangle Select tool) to select a piece of the text
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (Float)
3. begin moving the piece into position and hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> as you move it to constrain it to a vertical move
4. anchor the text back to its layer by pressing
   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (Anchor)
5. when you have finished use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Crop Tool)
   to crop the image.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I didn't know about ctrl+shift+L, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Other solution:

- Get/install the [`ofn-guillotine-layers` script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)
- Add horizontal guides to your image to frame the white space (or the useful space)
  [image]
- Invoke `Layer>Guillotine` to split your layer in multiple layers along the guides.
- Delete the white space layers
- Finally, either

  - move the remaining layers by hand
  - get/install the [`arrange-layers` script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/), and use `Image>Arrange layers>Space>Vertically` and give a spacing of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this painlessly with [Crop Out](https://toomuchsmart.com/cropout/).

1. Upload your image
2. Drag the highlight
3. Click to save.

Done in seconds!